# Using SDL_SetWindowIcon is not working properley

Tags: c++, icons, game-engine, sdl-2

I am attempting to program a game engine using SDL and glew with picoPNG as an image loader. I was attempting to make a system to set the icon for the window in my Window class and something strange happened. It appeared the icon worked for some images and it didn't for others. I barely know anything about how SDL_Surface works so I used some websites to find some information. (I can't post links to them because I only have 8 out of 10 required reputation)

### My code:

```
void Window::setWindowIcon(const std::string& filePath) {

    //read file
    std::vector<unsigned char> in;
    std::vector<unsigned char> out;

    unsigned long width, height;

    //Use my file loading class to read the image file
    if (DPE::IOManager::readFileToBuffer(filePath, in) == false) {
        fatalError("Failed to open " + filePath);
    }

    int errorCode = DPE::decodePNG(out, width, height, &(in[0]), in.size());
    if (errorCode != 0) {
        fatalError("Failed to decode png file!");
    }

    Uint32 rmask = 0x000000ff;
    Uint32 gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    Uint32 bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    Uint32 amask = 0xff000000;

    _sdlSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)&out[0], width, height, 32, width * 4, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

    if (_sdlSurface == NULL) {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        fatalError("Failed to create surface!");
    }

    SDL_SetWindowIcon(_sdlWindow, _sdlSurface);

    SDL_FreeSurface(_sdlSurface);
}
```

Finally, here are the two png files
[This one Worked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGVj.png)
[This one didn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qwVw.png)

The iteration through the code showed everything was fine and the only notification of an error was that the icon wasn't changing.

**Edit:** I have changed the color masks to be cross-Endian compatible

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
                int shift = 0;
                rmask = 0xff000000 >> shift;
                gmask = 0x00ff0000 >> shift;
                bmask = 0x0000ff00 >> shift;
                amask = 0x000000ff >> shift;
        #else // little endian, like x86
                rmask = 0x000000ff;
                gmask = 0x0000ff00;
                bmask = 0x00ff0000;
                amask = 0xff000000;
        #endif
```

Comment: Are you on a little endian machine? Also I can not help but notice that the second image contains transparent pixels, while the first doesn't. This probably plays its role for the bug. What exactly is that DPE::decodePNG,
a wrapper of picoPNG's decodePNG?

Comment: Other than that the snippet you posted seems fine.

Comment: +user183833 1.I am on a little endian 2.I tried another image that was with transparency and it worked and I noticed it was smaller so I tried shrinking my image and it didn't work 3.The decodePNG is the function in picoPNG and I added it to my engine namespace so I could use it for image loading

Comment: I have double checked and I had the right rgba masks for the little endian machine

Comment: Try putting and printing the result of SDL_GetError after every SDL call.
Note the errors in SDL work based on "last error" : 

> It is possible for multiple errors to occur before calling SDL_GetError(). Only the last error is returned.

So because of that I print the error result immediately after any `SDL_` call as a sanity check often helps with smaller things I've found.

Comment: Then there are two possible places in this snippet where the problem may be, one is reading the raw file. Check if the byte count has the expected value after reading it. And the other place is in the decoding itself. Check width, height and the size of the output buffer whether they have the expected values after the decoding.

Comment: Also [this](http://pastebin.com/Pd8MzutE) snippet I tested on my machine and it works fine with both images. I use [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) for the loading. You can get it on the link it is just one big file. Use stb_image and the snippet to check if that works. If not there is something else with your installation probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. It appears that when I was using the alpha pixel, it took up 8 more bpp so I decreased the file size to 75x75 and the image worked.